# Google forms upload file folder view/tree

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I know that Google Forms is non-dynamic, but I thought it's worth asking. Perhaps there's a solution that works around this static-ness.

In a nutshell, I'd like to allow user to choose to which folder they upload a file using a google form. I saw that some 3rd party services have (or had) this feature, such as [K2](https://help.k2.com/onlinehelp/k2five/userguide/5.3/default.htm#How-Tos/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive/UsingTreeControl.htm). Something that looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: For example, although this is not tree view type, how about a sample using a select box? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/96166a32e7781fee22da9e498b2289d0

Comment: Why not use the Picker API @ https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - Thanks. This does seem to function exactly as we want. however, it also seems that loading this API will complicate the script. The script is part of a system which used throughout the company on an almost minute-basis. Employees/uses won't wait so long for each execution. It also creates a small security issue by the need to send data back and forth. Can you think of a simpler solution? Perhaps there's a library that has a similar function?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add feature like that in Google Forms is by using a web browser extension paired with a Google Apps Script project.

One example of implementation of such solution is [EquatIO](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/equatio-math-made-digital/hjngolefdpdnooamgdldlkjgmdcmcjnc)<sup>1</sup>. This Chrome extension adds a mathematical formula editor to the respondent view.

NOTES:

I'm not related to the EquatIO team in anyway, actually I didn't used it recently. I learnt about this extension in the stand of one of their partners in an education conference held in Monterrey, Mexico.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how this extension answer my question, or even relate to it :)

Comment: @user13708028 I mentioned the extension as an example of how to achieve what you are looking for. If you want a more specific answer I suggest you post a question about how to make a web browser extension to add the folder tree viewer (obviously after you did a good search/research about that).

Comment: I'm not looking to make a web extension for general use. It's for a very specific code which isn't public.

Comment: You could create a web browser extension for personal use. Another possible option could be to use a userscript as a bookmarklet or an userscript handler like greasemonkey/tampermonkey